# How to select entire minimum data record from two rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server 2012 which returns the following result,

```
ID    IssueID    UpdateUserID
-----------------------------
205     105          25
208     105          28
```

I want to select minimum id row from this above set like this,

```
ID    IssueID    UpdateUserID
-----------------------------
205     105          25
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps you could start by looking up the MIN function

Comment: `select top 1 from (... order by id asc)`

Comment: I used min function but it gave me both rows. For Top keyword, this may not always be the first row. But I think I can first order the records in ascending order and then select top 1. But is there any simpler approach?

Comment: Yeah actually `TOP` is what you want not `MIN` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, there's a [TOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463(v=sql.110).aspx) keyword you can add to your query. Assuming your ID is unique:

```
select top 1 *
from MyTable
order by ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expressions can make this easy.

```
WITH [MinRowIds] AS (
  SELECT [IssueID], MIN([ID]) AS [minId]
  FROM [Issues]
  GROUP BY [IssueID]
)
SELECT [ID], [IssueID], [UpdateUserID]
FROM [Issues]
INNER JOIN [MinRowIds]
  ON (
    ([MinRowIds].[IssueId] = [Issues].[IssueID])
    AND ([MinRowIds].[minId] = [Issues].[ID])
  )
ORDER BY [IssueID]
```